# PHP file upload to user folder

Tags: php

Ok, so this is my script which registrates users, and upon successful registration, creates user subfolder (based on POST_ed username) in users folder. There are 2 scripts: register.php, and addfile.php. Thing is, script uploads files to users folder, not to created users subfolder. Any ideas how to modify scripts in order to upload file to users subfolder ? Thank you.

this is register.php:

```
session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) != '') {
        header ("Location: home.php");
    }

    require_once ('dbconnect.php');

        if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
    {
        $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

        $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='".$uname."'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);

            if ($num > 0)  { 
                ?>
                    <script>alert('Duplicate username');</script>
                <?php

            }
                else {
                    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$upass')")) {
                        ?>
                            <script>alert('Successfully registered');</script>
                        <?php

                        $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
                        $foldername = $_POST['uname'];
                        $path = "users/";
                        $complete = $path.$foldername;

                        if (mkdir($complete, 0770)) {
                            ?>
                                <script>alert('Folder <?php echo "\"$foldername\""; ?> has been created');</script>
                            <?php
                        }
                            else {
                                ?>
                                    <script>alert(Folder not created);</script>
                                <?php
                            }               
                    }

                }   
    }
```

and this is (addfile.php):

```
$folder = "users/";
$filename = $_FILES['filep']['name'];
$filedir = $folder.$filename;

if ($_POST['action'] == "Load") {

    if (file_exists($filedir)) {
        ?>
            <script>alert('File" <?php echo $_FILES["filep"]["name"] . "already exists."; ?>');</script>
        <?php
    }
        elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filep']['tmp_name'], $filedir)) {

            ?>
                <script>alert('File "<?php echo "$filename"; ?> "loaded');</script>
            <?php               
        }
            else {
                ?>
                    <script>alert('File not loaded');</script>
                <?php
            }
}
```

Comment: Is the username accessible anywhere in `addfile.php`? It should be in `$filedir`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: No, i dont have username reference in addfile.php

Comment: So `$_SESSION['user']` is not populated or users don't have to login to upload? If there is no way to identify the user on the upload script you can't put it in `their` folder.

Comment: This is how $_SESSION['user'] is populated in login.php:     if ($num['password'] == $upass) {
     $_SESSION['user'] = $num['user_id'];
     header ("Location: home.php");

Comment: So the user should be logged in on the addfile page, right? If so use the SESSIOn value and add it to the path where the file is being uploaded.

Comment: u could add permission for users folder 0777

Comment: @chris85 So, `session_start` should be added to addfile.php ?

Comment: Yes, and then pull in the username from the session.

Answer (score 0):

you just lack of the $_SESSION['user'] in your addfile.php (upload file is only for users so you need to have youre session started with a populated $_SESSION['user'], if not its a problem of conception on your part )

```
$filedir = $folder.$_SESSION['user'].'/'.$filename;
```

and now in your register.php before 'Successfully registered' alert :

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['uname'];
```

and dont forget the

```
session_start();
```

and to close your db connection

Comment: Hm error: `Warning: move_uploaded_file(users/85/something.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\addfile.php on line`

Comment: And are you sure the folder is well created ? the folder users is on the same level than the  script ? and use mysql_insert_id() to set $_SESSION['user']

Comment: @ MaximeK $_SESSION['user'] is allready defined in logon script: `if ($num['password'] == $upass) {  $_SESSION['user'] = $num['user_id'];  header ("Location: home.php");  }`  Problem is, i dont know how to pass $_SESSION to addfile.php script

Comment: So how do you execute addfile.php ? if its when you submit your file ( which it needed to be ) just add session_start();

Comment: Its some kind od privilege rights, i bet on it, like ive said few posts earlier, i have an error `Warning: move_uploaded_file(users/85/something.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\addfile.php on line ...`, so it means user subfolder "85" is created, but i cant copy my uploaded file into it.

Comment: But are you sure the folder '85' is created and if its not created in the wrong place : with a path relative or absolute './users/85' or '/users/85' but not 'users/85'

Comment: Actually, there is no subfolder created, only error reports shows one. Were talking about XAMPP installation on local drive, and my variables with pathes are defined like:  `$folder = "users";  $userfolder = $_SESSION['user'];  $filename = $_FILES['filep']['name'];  $filedir = $folder.'/'.$userfolder.'/'.$filename;`

Comment: can you try with absolute path and put ini_set('display_errors', 1); and  
error_reporting(E_ALL); in the begining of your script plz

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); doesnt report anything unusual, and `!is_writable($filedir)` also reports error